# How do you add login and publish security to KOPS elasticsearch-logging for Kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kops

I'm utilizing the 1.7.0 install for the KOPS plugin for Elasticsearch and Kibana. I looked around but it's not really clear how you modify the ES setting to have basic auth. Preferably I would like to use azureAD plugin but honestly, I would take a defined basic auth user and password but I don't see any way to do that or any documentation from KOPS how to do that as well.

Does anyone know how to do this ? 
Here is the 1.7.0 yaml file from KOPS official plugins.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "services"
  - "namespaces"
  - "endpoints"
  verbs:
  - "get"

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  apiGroup: ""

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd-es
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-es

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: fluentd-es
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-es
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "namespaces"
  - "pods"
  verbs:
  - "get"
  - "watch"
  - "list"

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: fluentd-es
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-es
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd-es
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd-es
  apiGroup: ""

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-es
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: logging-elasticsearch.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: fluentd-es
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    version: v2.0.4
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-es
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
        version: v2.0.4
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: fluentd-es
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-es
        image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.22
        command:
          - '/bin/sh'
          - '-c'
          - '/usr/sbin/td-agent 2>&1 >> /var/log/fluentd.log'
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      #nodeSelector:
      #  alpha.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready: "true"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: logging-elasticsearch.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "Elasticsearch"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: db
  selector:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: logging-elasticsearch.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-logging
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: elasticsearch-logging
      containers:
      - image: k8s.gcr.io/elasticsearch:v5.6.4
        name: elasticsearch-logging
        resources:
          # need more cpu upon initialization, therefore burstable class
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: db
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: es-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: "NAMESPACE"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: es-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "default"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: logging-elasticsearch.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kibana-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kibana-logging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana-logging
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.4
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_URL"
            value: "http://elasticsearch-logging:9200"
          - name: "SERVER_BASEPATH"
            value: "/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging"
          - name: "XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED"
            value: "false"
          - name: "XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED"
            value: "false"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
          name: ui
          protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-addon: logging-elasticsearch.addons.k8s.io
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ui
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
```

Is it XPACT security that I'm supposed to enable?

How do I configure xpact through the yaml or rather I thought xpact was a premium feature of elasticsearch..

Sorry the docs aren't clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

To add authentication to elasticsearch is not a completely trivial issue.

One of the ways, and probably simplest one,  is to go with `xpack` which is now embeded in upstream ES codebase, but it requires a commercial license for some of its features, including security.

Personally I ended up using ReadonlyREST to secure my ES/Kibana instance with basic level of authentication, rough on edges when using free version, but good enough for me.

Last but not least, you can secure elasticsearch traffic with mTLS provided by ie. Istio on network level.